# Why does NLog stops logging

Tags: c#, nlog

I now got this annoying problem about using NLog. My config file is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
           <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
<!-- go to http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file for more information -->

<targets>
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"  filename = "Logfile.txt" /> 
</targets>

<rules>  
<logger name="Program" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
<logger name="traincheck" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
 </nlog>
```

And I have windows media player in my winform with an "Open" button. The code is as following:

```
private void Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = camera_dir;
        logger.Info("External file opening and playing ");

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "(avi,mp3,wav,mp4,mov,wmv,mpg)   |*.avi;*.mp3;*.wav;*.mp4;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpgn|all files|*.*";

            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }

    }
```

I just want that when I click the button, the openFileDialog shows out, and I can choose a file to play, and this event could be logged (logger.Info("External file opening and playing "). This process has no problem. The problem is that the successive operations ("Next" button clicking, showing/hiding playlist etc) are not logged anymore! (I put a logger.Info(...) inside every of these events)

If I insert a break point in other logger.Info(), for example inside Nextbutton_click, when I click the "Next" button the program breaks at that point, but nothing is logged (No information written in the log file). I've no idea what happened after the logging of open file. Anybody got any idea about this or any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Where are those other events located? In the same form? Double check that the instance of `logger` in each statement is the same. (That's just a wild-guess, by the way)

Comment: Yeah all the events are in the same form, and the logger in each statement is exactly the same. It's strange that all other events are logged fine. When this event happen, the logger seems not work any more!

Comment: Use openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true.  Some odds you'll find the correct Logfile.txt back now.  Not using full path names for files is never not a mistake.

Comment: Yep - exactly what @HansPassant just said. You need to specify the FULLY qualified path for your logfile in the NLog config section.

Comment: @HansPassant Amazing! That's it and thank you very much! Is it that without this restore directory command, the logging process will just stop there and not proceed? How does it have sth to do with using full path name?

Answer (score 2):

We had a WEB API service using NLOG, logging for months. But one day it stops logging all of a sudden.

The reason was that the administrator added a new role permissions to the log folder and it somehow removed the previous permissions and NLOG stopped logging.

However, I learnt that using the below setting in Nlog.Config will help you catch such silent failures

internalLogLevel="Error"